# sending data from a javascript form

Tags: javascript

I am sending some data that it is in a table and a form .my problem is it will send the whole variables in the table . the destination  IP is a microcontroller and I need to  send some of the variables not the whole variables  .

```
<html>
<head>
  </head>
 <body>
<form name=myForm onsubmit=return validateForm() method=post>
<table>  <tr>
     <td>Device Info :</td>
 <td><input type=text name=dev-info id=01  size=3  value= ></td>
  <td> <input type=submit value=Apply/change></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MAC Adress :</td>
   <td><input type=text name=mac-addr id=02 size=3  value= ></td>
  <td> <input type=submit  value=Apply/change></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>IP Adress :</td>
    <td><input type=text name=ip-addr id=03 size=3  value= ></td>
  <td> <input type=submit value=Apply/change></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Gateway Adress :</td>
    <td><input type=text name=gate-addr id=04 size=3  value= ></td>
  <td> <input type=submit value=Apply/change></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Subnet Mask :</td>
     <td><input type=text name=sub-msk id=05 size=3  value= ></td>
  <td> <input type=submit value=Apply/change></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Ntp Server IP :</td>
   <td><input type=text name=ntp-ip id=06 size=3  value= ></td>
  <td> <input type=submit value=Apply/change></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
<input type=submit action=http://192.168.1.250 value=Apply/Reboot>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why include them if they're not all required?

Comment: Only input with `name` attribute are sending by the form. Remove this attribute where you don't want to send the data

Answer (score 0):

Rmove `name="ntp-ip"` from

`<input type=text name="ntp-ip" id=06 size=3>`

if you dont want to post the value when form submits.And do the same for rest.

Comment: but when I remove the name in the blocks it wil send nothing. I want every button in every block just send the data in its block .

Comment: Yes it wont but remove name from fields which you dont want to post and keep the names which you want to get.

Comment: but I want every button in every block send its own variable data.